# Javafx adding new tab with fxml on click

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am trying to add a new tab with fxml

I am trying this code:

```
Tab sd=new Tab("Customeradd");
sd.setContent(Source.sourceFor("","Customeradd.fxml"));
tabpanel.getTabs().add(sd);
```

and i am getting syntax error on line  `sd.setContent(Source.sourceFor("","Customeradd.fxml"));` and `tabpanel` is my `TabPane`.

Error Look Like

[image]

Help Me please

Comment: What is the error? What does `Source.sourceFor(...)` return?

Comment: it return a syntax error. and i want to load a fxml in tab is there any new way

Comment: No-one will really be able to help you unless you can tell us the return type of `Source.sourceFor(...)`, and what "syntax error" you are getting.

Comment: I have update my question with a picture

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have a FXML at the same directory as the class where you will load it from, you should do something like this (if your FXML defines a TabPane):

```
 TabPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("SomeWidget.fxml"));
```

Now, suppose you have a nice Tab in a MyTab.fxml file:

```
pane.getTabs().addAll((Tab)FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("MyTab.fxml")));
```

Really easy!

Comment: but i want to load fxml file in a tabs

Comment: Just make a fxml with a Tab, then say ``Tab t = FXMLLoader.load(...)``

Comment: Edited answer showing how to add a tab... but notice that if you can, you should just declare the TabPane and the Tabs all in the same FXML. You should only use Java to add Tabs like this if you're doing it dynamically.

Comment: error `java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane cannot be cast to javafx.scene.control.Tab`

Comment: If you have an AchorPane in your FXML, do ``AnchorPane anchorPane = FXMLLoader...`` and then ``tab.setContent(anchorPane)``.