# Building seperate tabs from same FXML with Java

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

How can I load the same FXML hierarchy into 2 different roots?
I've tried this:

```
protected void openPrivateSession(String remoteNick, int port, boolean isHost) {
    FXMLLoader loader =
        new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("PrivateTab.fxml"));
    try {
        PrivateChat pcc = new PrivateChatController(remoteNick, port, isHost);
        loader.setController(pcc);
    if (isHost) {
        connectRemoteUser(remoteNick, pcc.getPort());
    }
    Tab privateChat = new Tab(remoteNick);
    loader.setRoot(privateChat);
    loader.load();
    clientController.addPrivateChatTab(privateChat);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In the client program. this is the client controller:

```
public class ClientController implements Initializable {
    private Client associatedClient;
    private String hostname;
    private int port;

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private String title;

    @FXML
    private VBox nickList;

    @FXML
    private TextArea chatArea;

    @FXML
    private TextField msgBar;

    @FXML
    private Button sendButton;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem connectDisconnect;

    @FXML
    private TabPane privateChatPane;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem settingsButton;

    @FXML
    private Stage settings;

    .
    .
    .
```

}

But that loads the same privateChat tab into the same client (instead of one locally and one remote - that means that `privateChatPane` and probably all the other FXML objects have the same reference).

So I guess my final question is... how can you inject the same FXML into 2 different objects and preserve their uniqueness?

Ok MCVE:

```
class classA extends Application{

 public static void main(String[] args){ launch(args); }

 private ClassAController cac;

 public void start(Stage s){
  FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ClassA.fxml");
  loader.setController(cac = new ClassAController());
  s.setScene(new Scene(loader.load()));
  s.show();
 }

 public void onSomeEvent(String s){
  FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("PrivateChat.fxml");
  loader.setController(new PrivateChatController());
  Tab tab = new Tab(s);
  loader.setRoot(tab);
  cac.addPrivateChatTab(tab);
 }
}

class ClassAController implements Initializeable{
@FXML TabPane privateChatPane;

 public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resource){}

 //Using this method causes the add of the same Tab twice to the same app instead once for each app
 public void addPrivateChatTab(Tab privateChat){
 privateChatPane.getTabs().add(privateChat);
}
```

I'm running 2 instances of ClassA app. when I use addPrivateChatTab() I get the same tab twice in the same app instance.

Comment: Your code doesn't make very much sense to me. E.g. pcc is not defined. And the clientController is not used by the FXMLLoader. You're talking about 2 "roots" and a "remote" tab, but I don't see any of this in your code. It's hard to tell what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: According to these partial codes, I guess there is only one instance of clientController, and clientController.addPrivateChatTab(privateChat) will add all privateChat tabs to this clientController. There is no remoteController in your code. Isn't it?

Comment: No, you are correct uluk. Of course this is partial code I wouldn't post the whole thing its too big.
There's one clientController for each client (2 instances) but they are injected with the same FXML which creates problem for me.
How can I achieve multiple instances of clientController from the same FXML? is that even possible?

Comment: @Puce pcc is defined, I modified the code and forgot the extra C in the post :)

Comment: @MuliYulzary, Yes it is possible but not the code you have now. The openPrivateSession() method always add the privateChat to the clientController instance only. You haven't shown the second instance of clientController. Even though there is only one "PrivateTab.fxml" file, the openPrivateSession() method creates and loads new instance of it. I think you need to explain what do you means "client program". Are you launching multiple threads of your app?

Comment: It is a part of multi-client chat app. My goal is to have each independent client able to interact with the server. Yes the app is heavily threadded but only server-side.
PS: I thought injecting the FXML into different instances of controllers would do the trick but it didn't so I'd be glad if you could shed some light on that :)

Comment: @UlukBiy for the record. I'm launching the same application twice on my PC (the app extends Application and I use the non-static launch(args) in main(args[])

Comment: Really nobody knows how to do this? that's a shame...

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. Your code doesn't correspond to what you describe at all: you don't have two different roots into which you're loading the FXML. Perhaps you should create a specific example that shows the issue (and nothing else), and post the complete code for that.

Comment: @James_D I'm getting a feeling you didn't take the time to read the code because as you can clearly see, everytime openPrivateSession() is called - it creates a new instance of privateChat (which is a Tab) and sets it as root BEFORE loading the content.

Comment: But you are adding them all to the same `clientController` instance... Perhaps you need to clarify how it is behaving differently to the way you want.

Comment: @James_D now you get to my point and my question... I'm running the same client twice (2 instances in parallel) that makes 2 separate instances of clientController (because the code for that part is literally the same in logic of openPrivateSession()) which means - 2 instances of clientController -> 2 instances of privateChatPane (TabPane) -> 2 instances of privateChat (Tab). I'm getting the same tab twice in the same privateChatPane soooo...?

Comment: Your code only shows one instance of `clientController`. Please create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (I would like to emphasize *minimal* and *complete*) that demonstrates the problem. It is impossible to help with the information you have provided.

Comment: @James_D I added MVCE as requested

Comment: Well it doesn't matter now, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I solved the problem and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24850050/javafx-adding-new-tab-with-fxml-on-click) post was helpful.
My code changed just a little bit:

```
protected void addPrivateChatTab(String remoteNick, int port, boolean isHost) {
 FXMLLoader loader =
  new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("PrivateTab.fxml"));
 try {
  loader.setController(new PrivateChat(remoteNick, port, isHost));
  if (isHost) {
   associatedClient.connectRemoteUser(remoteNick, PrivateChat.getPort());
  }
  Tab privateChat = new Tab(remoteNick);
  SplitPane sp = loader.load();
  privateChat.setContent(sp);
  addPrivateChatTab(privateChat);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

To be more specific for googlers:

1. Create the wrapping object (`Tab privateChat = new Tab(remoteNick)`).
2. Load the content of the dynamic object you are about to add (`SplitPane sp = loader.load()`).
3. Set the content of the wrapping object to the object you loaded (`privateChat.setContent(sp)`)
4. Finally add the finished object to the stage/parent node (`addPrivateChatTab(privateChat)`)